# vectorizing matrix multiplication

Tags: matlab, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

I have two arrays, A (14x14) and B (14x256x200). I need to matrix multiply A by each page of B, as in

```
for i = 1:200
    C(:, :, i) = A*B(:,:,i) 
end
```

I would like to vectorize this operation and have looked at 
    bsxfun, arrayfun, splitapply
but none do the trick.

I think this could be accomplished with a clever reshape or kron? any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

Reshape `B` to `2D`, perform the `matrix-multiplication` with `A` to reduce the first dimension of `B` and second of `A` and get a `2D` product output. Finally reshape back the product to desired `3D` output, like so -

```
[m,n,p] = size(B); %// Store size parameters
C = reshape(A*reshape(B,m,[]),m,n,p)
```

---

### Benchmarking

```
num_iter = 100; %// Number of iterations to run benchmarks

for k = 1:50000
    tic(); elapsed = toc(); %// Warm up tic/toc.

end

%// Size parameters and setup input arrays
m = 14;
n = 256;
p = 200;
A = rand(m,m);
B = rand(m,n,p);

disp('---------------- With loopy approach')
tic
for ii = 1:num_iter
    C = zeros(m,n,p);
    for i = 1:p
        C(:, :, i) = A*B(:,:,i);
    end
end
toc

disp('---------------- With vectorized approach')
tic
for ii = 1:num_iter
    [m,n,p] = size(B);
    Cout = reshape(A*reshape(B,m,[]),m,n,p);
end
toc

error_check = isequal(C,Cout) %// 1 means good
```

Output -

```
---------------- With loopy approach
Elapsed time is 1.679919 seconds.
---------------- With vectorized approach
Elapsed time is 1.496923 seconds.
error_check =
     1
```

Comment: ah you beat me to it, but I think in this particular scenario, the for loop seems to be faster.

Comment: @GameOfThrows Really? Well, I have added some benchmark results. I am guessing we are benchmarking differently.

Comment: I guess it might just be my old version, I'm stuck with 2010b at office, I guess vectorized method is faster :)

Comment: very nice @Divakar may you add the line to your benchmark 'isequal(cout, c)' to verify equality?

Comment: @crowdedComputeeer Good suggestion! Added that.

Comment: do you think it would matter that the inputs are complex?

Comment: @crowdedComputeeer I would think it should not. Matrix-multiplication being too basic, should take care of that! :)

Comment: What's the purpose of warming up tic/toc?

Comment: have you ever used MATLAB's time it function? For benchmarking I believe it handles warm-up issues all that's required is embedding the operation in an anonymous function… Of course no output is required so

Comment: @crowdedComputeeer Of course that's the standard/prescribed way with the hassle of dealing with multiple files for multiple funcs. One can do the same with these tic-tocs, with the addition of warming up and the most important thing is to use a number of iterations (num_iter) used here to make sure the runtime being reported is at least close to 1sec mark (more the better).

Comment: @DavidKelley Well tic/tocs being funcs have their own runtime overheard. That can't be eliminated and maybe negligible, but to minimize that overhead, one can run them a fair amount of time before actually using it for timings. I guess it does some caching that way. I adopted this as a best practice and I don't really remember when/where did I pick that up from, but I guess I remember the basic idea behind it. Hope that made some sense! :)

Comment: This is nice seeing how `for` and vectorized are almost matching in performance.  Are you using R2015b with the improved JIT?

Comment: @rayryeng Nope, still on my old 2012A. My gut feeling says the runtimes would be similar. More like my wish feeling maybe :D

Comment: @rayryeng I think the reason behind *not-huge* speedup is that the loop iterates through `200` iterations which isn't a big number and also is a comparable number to other dimension of `256`. I just changed datasizes to test out other size variations. I changed `256` to `14`, i.e. `b` is `(14,14,200)` keeping rest the same and speedup becomes `~10x`. Next up, changed `200` to `14`, i.e. `b` is now `(14,14,14)` and the speedup becomes `~2x`. So, I guess at the original one of `(14,256,200)`, huge memory transfers needed for one-time matrix-multiplication is just putting off the system memory.

Comment: Ah that actually makes sense. Thanks for the benchmarking!